# Scale algorithm not exact?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, algorithm

I'm trying to create this very simple algorithm to size, position and transform (scale) a div. For some reason the algorithm doesn't work exactly. If you take a look at the jsfiddle i made, when you click the div, it scales, but the edges go out of the window. If my math isn't really bad, this should not happen with this algorithm. Why is this happening, and what can i do to fix it?

PS: No console log (no errors)
Any help is very much appreciated! :3

For some reason, i have to put some code in to upload jsfiddle's, so here is the algorithm, the rest is on the jsfiddle. :3

```
var me = $("#me");
var zoom = $("#me.zoom");
var win = $(window);

me.css({
    "top": win.height() / 2 - me.height() / 2 + "px",
    "left": win.width() / 2 - me.width() / 2 + "px"
});

me.on("click", function() {
    me.toggleClass("zoom");
    if(me.hasClass("zoom")) {
        me.css({
            "transform": "scale(" + win.width() / me.width() + ")",
            "-webkit-transform": "scale(" + win.width() / me.width() + ")"
        });
    } else {
        me.css({
            "transform": "scale(1)",
            "-webkit-transform": "scale(1)"
        });
    }
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/k8vkL343/2/)

Comment: Your 1% padding on `#me` is the portion that is going outside the window. You could put it on the `<p>` instead, or add a child `<div>` inside of `#me` and put it on that.

Comment: Thank you. This was exactly what i was looking for. What stupid little mistakes :3

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Cory in the comment the `1%` padding is what's going outside the window. You might want to use `outerHeight()` and `outerWidth()` instead as shown on this update on the Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/k8vkL343/3/